# Disable WindowsIoT On-screen keyboard TextBox Auto-correct

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windowsiot

This is for a UWP app deployed to a Raspberry Pi 3 with a touch screen. On-screen keyboard enabled.

I have a `TextBox` control for ASCII commands to be sent to a device. Is there a way to disable or prevent auto correction on a textbox control when using the on-screen touch keyboard? Is there a way to do that in XAML?

It is nice to have auto-correction available. I'd hate to disable it completely, but I suppose that's also an option.

Comment: Set an `InputScope` that doesn't offer corrections. Check MSDN for details

Comment: I already tried setting it to `Formula`, `NativeScript`, but it doesn't seem to function on WindowsIoT. I can't set it to any of the number or other input scopes limiting the ASCII characters I can put in.

Comment: Have you tried setting: `<TextBox IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"/>`?

Comment: Of course, I completely glossed over those. Thanks @Romasz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable autocomplete and text prediciton with [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox)  properties: *IsSpellCheckEnabled*, *IsTextPredictionEnabled*.

Setting `<TextBox IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"/>` should do the job.

Howeer if you need more sophisticated solution with some modifications when on-screen keyboard is showing, then you can probably use *InputPane* class for this.